# How can I start PostgreSQL 9.6 server after installing on Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

I need to upgrade my PostgreSQL from 9.5 to 9.6.8 on Ubuntu 16.10, so I installed PostgreSQL 9.6 by running "sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.6", and it worked well.

But after that, when I run "pg_lsclusters", nothing is displayed.
Even when I run "cd /etc/postgresql/9.6/main", it tells me "No such file or directory".  But when I run "cd /etc/postgresql/9.5/main", then it goes to the directory.

I have no idea why that is, and how can I start 9.6 server?
Please see the attached image.

[image]

Comment: You didn't run [`initdb`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-initdb.html)

Comment: What do you mean, please?